# "На английском" or "по-английски"?

Tags: выбор-слова

I was wondering if there's any difference between

```
на английском
```

and

```
по-английски
```

(for example when asking how to say something in English).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They are more or less interchangeable as far as verbs for speaking and writing are concerned; there's a slight idiomatic preference for *по-английски* when referring to speaking and for *на английском* for writing. However, *понимать* "to understand" requires *по-английски*, while you have to use *на английском* if it refers to a noun rather than a verb — such as *разговор* "conversation" or *книга* "book".

In general, *на английском* is narrower in meaning, implying as it does the word *языке*, whereas *по-английски* is not limited to language. Thus *детектив на английском* is "a detective story in English" whereas *детектив по-английски* is "a detective story *à l'anglais*", "a very English detective story".

Answer (score 11):

They are almost interchangeable.

Though, you should always remember the following:

- **«по-английски», «по-японски»** etc. are about **action being performed** "English-way", "Russian-way" etc. It is used for real actions and for some stuff that is "like English people do" (for example, "сэндвичи по-английски" if sandwiches in UK were somehow special).
- **«на английском», «на русском»** are about some **content being written** (spoken) in some language. You can also use them to talk about the ability to speak a language.

Which means that a book, subtitles, an e-mail or an inscription can only be "на английском" but not "по-английски" (unless you want to imply that they bear some English flavour, as Nikolay Ershov illustrated with «детектив по-английски»)

It also means that sushi and pelmeni that English people do in some unique way can only be «пельмени по-английски», «суши по-английски» (even if I made them up, and those do not exist).

As a bonus, since there is no American or Austrian language, you only have «по-американски», «по-австрийски». Things can be done "American way" but cannot be written or spoken in American languge.

Comment: You can say "напиши по-русски", "скажи по-русски" and that would mean "write it down in Russian (language)", "say it in Russian (language)". Especially "скажи по-русски" is used in 99.9% of cases when people want somebody to say something in Russian.

Answer (score 4):

Others have answered the question, but note there are some languages where the "по-английски" form doesn't really exist because the name of the language is not in adjectival form.

- говорить на иврите (Hebrew = иврит)
- говорить на хинди (Hindi = хинди = indeclinable)