# What does "на русском" mean?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

In the [Stack Overflow for Russian (beta)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), you can see the phrase *на русском* in the title, which I'm sure means *in Russian*.

However, I'm not sure why the site expresses the phrase as `на русском`. Specifically,

1. It seems that `русском` looks like instrumental (not sure but just I guess), but why does `на` not take either prepositional or accusative, which I learned `на` should take.
2. If you mean *I speak Russian.*, you say *Я говорю по-русски.*. Is there any difference between the two word (`по-русски` and `на русском`)?

Comment: на русском is indeed prepositional, but русский is an adjective and declines like an adjective. For a language like иврит (Hebrew), the name of the language is not an adjectival form and the prepositional declines like a noun = на иврите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Русском` is prepositional. Masculine adjective prepositionals look like noun instrumentals. The instrumental here would be `русским`. The difference between *на* and *по-* with languages [has been asked about here](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8037/%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8/8038). In this particular case, `по-русски` would have been, at least theoretically, ambiguous — with an alternative reading of "Stack Exchange, Russian-style" — while `на русском` can only refer to the language.

Comment: Thanks. Does `по-` only take an adjective? Or does it sometimes take a noun, too?

Comment: @Blaszard Adjectives only, I think.

Comment: @Blaszard "По+noun" is just Dative case which must be written in two words. E.g. "Говорить по-русски" vs "Экзамен по русскому (языку)". Prefix "По-" (with dash) is used with adjectives and posessive pronouns only (e.g. "по-нашему").

Comment: @user4419802 Actually it's not dative; it's old plural neuter instrumental of the short form. *По-русски* is a contamination of *русски* with *по русскому* or older *по русску*.